# How to dispose a view holder linked to certain card in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am working on an android project in which I want to remove the item from vertical recycler view by swiping an item to right or left. As far as it comes to deleting the item, I am able to do that correctly. The issue arises after I delete the item and call `notifyDataSetChanged().`

Now while refreshing items, Adapter uses previous view holders to display cards. But while deleting an item I displaced some of its layouts to left and right. So when new item occupies the same view holder all the translation is preserved and 
 some views of the new item are thus created out of bounds of the screen(as I displaced that view holder while deleting the previous item that occupied that spot).

So my question is (solution to any one of the following will solve the issue I am facing),

> 1. Is there "free" function like c++ in Java? So that I can free that view holder.
> 2. How to make sure that recycler view doesn't reuse particular view holder?
> 3. How to reset layout of to the original state before all animations were done? So that I can just reset all translations

Thank you.

**Edits:**

Below are the codes for adapter and view holder if someone wants to have a look at them. 
As view holder is too large to understand directly, SO here is summery for functions used in it:

> 1. init -> just set on click listener.
> 2. updateUI -> sets some more listener and set text and other fields from card.
> 3. pressDown -> is called when MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN.
> 4. pressUP ->  is called when MotionEvent.ACTION_UP.
> 5. animateViewDisappear -> listener for animation.
> 6. archive -> delete an element and tell adapter data is change.
> 7. pressMove -> sense when motion happens after clicking button.
> 8. toggleShowHideView -> change visibility of some view.
> 9. closeOpenedLayout -> Close some expanded layouts.

Adapter:

```
class LocalAdapter(var localCardsInfo : ArrayList<LocalModel>?,var fragment: LocalListingFragment) : RecyclerView.Adapter<LocalHolder>() {

    fun refreshDataOnOrientationChange(mLocalCards : ArrayList<LocalModel>?){
        if (localCardsInfo!!.size>0)
            localCardsInfo!!.clear()
        localCardsInfo = mLocalCards
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return localCardsInfo!!.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LocalHolder, position: Int) {
        if (localCardsInfo!=null)
            holder.updateUI(position,localCardsInfo!![position])
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): LocalHolder {
        val card_a : View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_local_a,parent,false)
        return LocalHolder(card_a,fragment)
    }

}
```

view holder:

```
class LocalHolder(itemView : View,val fragment: LocalListingFragment) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),OpenedLayoutManagerLocal{

    private val TAG = "iotcontrollerapp.@Debug"
    private var _xDelta: Float = 0f
    private var originalDelta : Float = 0f
    private var directionOut1 = false
    private var directionOut = false
    private var previousX = 0f

    var isFavourite : Boolean = false
    var isPropertyPanelOpen : Boolean = false

    val deviceName : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deviceNameLocal)
    val deviceRoom : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deviceRoomLocal)
    val deviceOnOff : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deviceOnOffLocal)

    val showHideLayout : LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.showHideLayoutLocal)
    val showHideProperties : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.showHidePropertiesLocal)
    val showHideButton : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.showHideButtonLocal)

    val favouriteButton : ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageFavouriteButtonLocal)
    val moveButton : MoveableViewImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageMoveButtonLocal)

    val changeFragmentToDetail : Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.changePropertiesLocal)

    val layoutForProperties : LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layoutForPropertyLocal)
    val baseForProperties : LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.baseForPropertyLocal)
    private var model : LocalModel? = null
    init {
        itemView.elevation = 0f
        showHideLayout.setOnClickListener({

            isPropertyPanelOpen = !isPropertyPanelOpen
            if (isPropertyPanelOpen){
                if (openedLayoutManagerLocal != this)
                    openedLayoutManagerLocal?.closeOpenedLayout()
                openedLayoutManagerLocal = this
                showHideProperties.text = fragment.getString(R.string.close_property_panel)
                showHideButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.animated_more_button_local)
            }
            else{
                showHideProperties.text = fragment.getString(R.string.open_property_panel)
                showHideButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.animated_more_button_reverse_local)
            }
            val mDrawable = showHideButton.drawable
            if (mDrawable is Animatable)
            {
                (mDrawable as Animatable).start()
            }
            toggleShowHideView()
        })
    }

    fun changeFavouriteButtonState(localModel: LocalModel){
        isFavourite = !isFavourite
        if (isFavourite){
            favouriteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.avd_heart_fill)
            val a = favouriteButton.drawable
            if(a is Animatable){
                a.start()
            }
            ALL_STATIC_CONSTANTS_AND_METHODS.saveIsFavourite(fragment.activity as Context,localModel.roomName.trim() + "$" + localModel.deviceName,true)
        }
        else{
            favouriteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.avd_heart_break)
            val a = favouriteButton.drawable
            if(a is Animatable){
                a.start()
            }
            ALL_STATIC_CONSTANTS_AND_METHODS.saveIsFavourite(fragment.activity as Context,localModel.roomName.trim() + "$" + localModel.deviceName,false)
        }
    }

    fun updateUI(position : Int , localModel: LocalModel){
        itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        itemView.archiveLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        model = localModel
        originalDelta = itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.x
        changeFragmentToDetail.setOnClickListener({
            fragment.handlerForDetail.sendEmptyMessage(position)
        })
        favouriteButton.setOnClickListener({
            changeFavouriteButtonState(localModel)
        })
        moveButton.setOnTouchListener({v: View?, event: MotionEvent? ->
            if (v == null || event == null) return@setOnTouchListener true
            when (event.action){
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    v.performClick()
                    pressUP(v,event)
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    pressDown(v,event)
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                    pressMove(v,event)
                }
                else -> {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Something happened")
                }
            }
            return@setOnTouchListener true
        })
        isFavourite = (ALL_STATIC_CONSTANTS_AND_METHODS.getIsFavourite(fragment.activity as Context,localModel.roomName.trim() + "$" + localModel.deviceName) ?: false)

        favouriteButton.setImageResource(if (isFavourite) R.drawable.vd_trimclip_heart_full else R.drawable.vd_trimclip_heart_empty)

        deviceRoom.text = localModel.roomName.split("_").dropLast(1).toTypedArray().joinToString(" ")
        deviceName.text = localModel.deviceName.split("_").dropLast(1).toTypedArray().joinToString(" ")
        deviceOnOff.text = if (localModel.isON) fragment.getString(R.string.device_on_off_on) else fragment.getString(R.string.device_on_off_off)

        val components = localModel.componentName.split(" ")
        val value = localModel.value.split(" ")
        val maxValue = localModel.maxValue.split(" ")
        val minValue = localModel.minValue.split(" ")
        if (layoutForProperties.childCount > 0)
            layoutForProperties.removeAllViews()
        if (components.size == value.size && minValue.size == maxValue.size && components.size == minValue.size){
            for (i in 0 until components.size){
                val layout : LinearLayout = LinearLayout.inflate(fragment.activity , R.layout.card_local_b , null) as LinearLayout
                layout.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.propertyLocal).text = components[i].replace("_"," ")
                layout.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.valueLocal).text = value[i]
                layout.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.rangeLocal).text = minValue[i] + " to " + maxValue[i]
                layoutForProperties.addView(layout)
            }

        }

    }

    private fun pressDown(imageButton: View, event: MotionEvent){
        fragment.mLayoutManager?.setScrollEnabled(false)
        openedLayoutManagerLocal?.closeOpenedLayout()
        _xDelta = itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.x - event.rawX
    }

    private fun pressUP(imageButton: View, event: MotionEvent){

        Log.e(TAG,"itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.x :: ${(itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.width / 3.toFloat()) - itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.x}")
        val status = (itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.width / 3.toFloat()) < itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.x
        val status1 = (itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.width / 2.toFloat()) < itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.x
        itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.animate()
                .x(if ((directionOut && status) || (status1 && directionOut1)) itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.width.toFloat() else originalDelta)
                .setDuration(100)
                .setListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener{
                    override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {
                        if ((directionOut && status) || (status1 && directionOut1)) {
                            itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.visibility = View.GONE
                            val anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(itemView.archiveLayout.measuredHeight, 0)
                            anim.addUpdateListener { valueAnimator ->
                                val `val` = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int
                                val layoutParams = itemView.archiveLayout.layoutParams
                                layoutParams.height = `val`
                                itemView.archiveLayout.layoutParams = layoutParams
                            }
                            anim.addListener(animateViewDisappear(this@LocalHolder))
                            anim.duration = 1000
                            anim.start()
                        }else{
                            fragment.mLayoutManager?.setScrollEnabled(true)
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                        if ((directionOut && status) || (status1 && directionOut1)) {
                            itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.visibility = View.GONE
                            val anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(itemView.archiveLayout.measuredHeight, 0)
                            anim.addUpdateListener { valueAnimator ->
                                val `val` = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int
                                val layoutParams = itemView.archiveLayout.layoutParams
                                layoutParams.height = `val`
                                itemView.archiveLayout.layoutParams = layoutParams
                            }
                            anim.addListener(animateViewDisappear(this@LocalHolder))
                            anim.duration = 1000
                            anim.start()
                        }else{
                            fragment.mLayoutManager?.setScrollEnabled(true)
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {

                    }

                    override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {

                    }
                }).start()
    }

    class animateViewDisappear(var i : LocalHolder) :Animator.AnimatorListener {
        override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {
            i.itemView.archiveLayout.visibility = View.GONE
            i.itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.visibility = View.GONE
            i.itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.x = i.originalDelta
            val layoutParams = i.itemView.archiveLayout.layoutParams
            layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            i.itemView.archiveLayout.layoutParams = layoutParams
            i.archived()
        }
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
            i.itemView.archiveLayout.visibility = View.GONE
            i.itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.visibility = View.GONE
            i.itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.x = i.originalDelta
            val layoutParams = i.itemView.archiveLayout.layoutParams
            layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            i.itemView.archiveLayout.layoutParams = layoutParams
            i.archived()
        }
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {

        }
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {

        }

    }

    private fun archived(){
        fragment.mLayoutManager?.setScrollEnabled(true)
        if (model != null) {
            ALL_STATIC_CONSTANTS_AND_METHODS.addToArchive(fragment.activity!!, model!!.roomName, model!!.deviceName)
            fragment.mAdapter?.refreshDataOnOrientationChange(LocalDataService.ourInstance.getNonArchivedItems(fragment.activity!!))
        }

    }


    private fun pressMove(imageButton: View, event: MotionEvent){
        directionOut1 = itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.x >= (previousX)
        directionOut = itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.x >= (previousX + 20)
        previousX = itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.x
        fragment.mLayoutManager?.setScrollEnabled(false)
        itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.animate()
                .x(event.rawX + _xDelta)
                .setDuration(0)
                .start()
    }

    fun toggleShowHideView(){
        changeFragmentToDetail.visibility = if (isPropertyPanelOpen) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
        layoutForProperties.visibility = if (isPropertyPanelOpen) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
        baseForProperties.visibility = if (isPropertyPanelOpen) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }

    override fun closeOpenedLayout() {
        if (isPropertyPanelOpen){
            isPropertyPanelOpen = !isPropertyPanelOpen
            showHideProperties.text = fragment.getString(R.string.open_property_panel)
            showHideButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.animated_more_button_reverse_local)
            val mDrawable = showHideButton.drawable
            if (mDrawable is Animatable)
            {
                (mDrawable as Animatable).start()
            }
            toggleShowHideView()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        var openedLayoutManagerLocal : OpenedLayoutManagerLocal? = null
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no "free" in java, and the situation you are facing has probably nothing to do with android's implementation of recycler view. I think you should post your view holder and adapter codes. The problem lies there.

Comment: @Debanjan please check edits in question. I added the code for view holder and adapter.

Comment: you need to reset views in the onBindViewHolder().  onBindViewHolder will be called even though views are reused. So you need to set the views to old state there.